# Mostrar texto sobre punto de google maps

Tags: c#, google-maps

quien me ayuda en lo siguiente:
Tengo un proyecto en el cual desde winform abro el navegador con la url de google maps especificando latitud y longitus, pasando los parametros en la url (Ejemplo: "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=17.43%2C60.65"), todo funciona bien y lo muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me falta es que necesito que encima del punto del mapa me aparezca un texto, algo como "Dirección de Pepito Perez". Entonces la pregunta sera ¿Como adiciono texto encima del punto de google maps? ojo que esto debe sar pasando parametros en la url (como en el ejemplo la latitud y longitud). Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código con el que pones el marcador?

Comment: Creo que e,l punto clave de la pregunta es que a la url que puse como ejemplo, como le adiciono un texto como parámetro que se visualice encima del punto rojo,???

Comment: En click del boton hay esto:

    System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" txtlatitud.Text + "%2c" + txtlongitud.text));

Esa línea abre el navegador con la url especificada, en esa url le paso dos parametros que son la latitud y la longitud que llegan a mostrar el punto rojo, pero quisiera pasar un tercer parámetro con un texto que se muestre en el mapa (Ejemplo: "Dirección de Pepito Peres").

Comment: Según este hilo en el [foro de soporte de Google Maps](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/I02V1BRIcFA), es posible añadir una pequeña etiqueta con el nombre de la localización usando un formato como este en la URL: https://maps.google.com/?q=ETIQUETA@LATITUD,LONGITUD. Pero he probado con esta URL: http://maps.google.com/?q=Capital+del+Santo+Reino@37.7908414,-3.8823917 y me funciona sólo en iOS y no en Android/escritorio

Comment: Bueno yo necesito que me funcione en cualquier navegador normal instalado en una pc. no es un sistema web o un app movil.

Comment: Seguramente necesitarás usar la API de Google Maps, y no sólo a través de la URL

Comment: Si tal vez, pero todo el sistema ya esta desarrollado, solo falta agregar ese parametro a la url y que se muestre en el navegador, manejar api y demas seria cambias mas grandes

Comment: Tal vez alguien tenga otra idea, tal vez hacer lo mismo con bings maps u otra web de mapas, la cosa es que pueda poner en el navegador una URL con latitud longitud y texto y se me muestra el texto en la ubicacion especificada en la latitud longitud

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes tu respuesta según los docs de google.
No pego el código porque sin especificar la api de google, lo ejecutarías en SO i no funcionaría.
Regístrate en google maps para obtener tu API, es facilito. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details)

Te dejo otra opción esta es con la url de la api de google pero sin una api key.
He sacado el código de una respuesta de SO en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31548993/4955542
**Es mejor usar la API Key es más seguro** para ti que te funcione en todos los navegadores, sin problemas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>test sandbox 8</title>

            <style type="text/css">
              #main {
                margin: 60px 15px; 
              }
              #map { 
                min-height: 600px; 
                min-width: 800px; 
              }
            </style>

                <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>
              // code to draw map
              var map;
              var col = '#FF0000';
              var link ;
              var latLng;
              var polypoints;

              function initialize() {
    var locations_programs = [
       ['Christie Lake Camp', 44.803033, -76.418031, 1, 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/map_pins/events/canoe-for-kids.png', ''],    
       ['Caldwell Community Centre', 45.373083, -75.735550, 1, 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/map_pins/events/caldwell-community-centre.png', ''],    
       ['Dempsey Community Centre', 45.401887, -75.627530, 1, 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/map_pins/events/dempsey-community-centre.png', ''],    
       ['Brewer Arena', 45.389560, -75.691445, 1, 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/map_pins/events/brewer-arena.png', '']

    ];

    var markersArray = [];
    var markers = {};
    var mapOptions = {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.4214, -75.6919),
        zoom: 10,
        scrollwheel: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
          },
        panControl: true,
            panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
          }
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);


     //***  PROGRAMS

      var marker, i;
      var id = 'programs';

      for (i = 0; i < locations_programs.length; i++) {  
        var id = 'programs' + i;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_programs[i][1], locations_programs[i][2]),
          map: map
          ,id: id
          ,icon: 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/new/blue_circle.png'
          ,url: locations_programs[i][5]
          ,zIndex:100
        });



          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
              this.setIcon('http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/map_pins/events/canoe-for-kids.png');
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(event) {
              this.setIcon('http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/new/blue_circle.png');
          });



      }
    }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
                 <div id="map"></div>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la url del google maps directamente **NO** se puede hacer lo que indicas.

Si quieres ver todo lo que se puede hacer sin la API (que es lo que estás haciendo) puedes mirar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24778057/1468942) que te indica todos los parámetros con los que puedes trabajar.